# How to capitalize the first letter of each word in an array using Array.map() with an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping, ecmascript-5

How to capitalize the first letter of each word in an array using Array.map() with an arrow function?

What I've tried so far:

```
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
days.map(day => day.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day.substr(1));
console.log(day);
```

Comment: It does work, it's just that `map()` returns the change in a new list rather than modifying the original list.

Comment: As @OmarEinea mentioned, map returns a new array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: FYI `Array#map` is an ES5 feature. You don't need to slap ES7 (2016) and ES8 on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map()` method does not mutate the values in the current array `days` but creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

In other words, the `map()` method does not make any changes to the array you're mapping but what it does is create a new array with the changes made.

So in order to access the new array that you got from `map()`, you need to assign the mapped array to a new variable say, `newDays` like this:

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
    
const newDays = days.map(day => day.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day.substr(1).toLowerCase());
    
console.log(newDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use  **map** :

```
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
const capitalDays = days.map( day => day.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day. substr(1));
```

Or use forEach method

```
days.forEach((day, index) => {
   days[index] = day.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day.substr(1).toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: Don't recommend `forEach` just because it's different.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. You have just two issues:

1) `map` returns a new array, it doesn't change the array

2) you are doing `console.log(day)`

```js
const days = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
console.log(days.map(day => day.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day.substr(1)));
```